# Hom of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

For any $R$-algebras $A$ and $B$,

doea their set of R-algebra morphisms $\mathrm{Hom}_{R_{\mathrm{Alg}}}(A,B)$ necessarily again have the strucutre of an $R$-algebra?

Comment: What would addition be?

Comment: I think that this is a very interesting question, since it is a common misconception that Hom sets between objects of an algebraic category have an algebraic structure too. And also, as my friendly disagreement with such an outstanding contributor as Zhen shows, some quite subtle points are involved. Energetically voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, $A$ be the trivial algebra $\{ 0 \}$ and let $B$ be any non-trivial algebra. Then $\mathrm{Hom}(A, B) = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\mathrm{Hom}_{R-{\mathrm{Alg}}}(A,B)$ is **never** an algebra if $B\neq 0$ because the zero map is not a morphism.
Indeed, the zero map sends $1_A$ to $0_B$ instead of sending $1_A$ to $1_B$ like any honest morphism should.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that a set is an algebra or not.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: of course it doesn't make sense in general. In the context of the question  the widespread misconception is that this hom set is an algebra *if you endow it with the structure deduced from that of the target*, for example taking for the zero of the hom set the map constantly equal to the zero of the target.

Comment: I stand by my answer and comment: you may downvote till you're blue in the face. And I advise good faith readers to remember the counterintuitive fact that often *Hom* sets between algebraic structures have no natural algebraic structure at all.

Comment: Just to be clear: I haven't downvoted your answer.